# How to fetch categories from nunit/xunt tests using powershell?

Tags: powershell, lambda, nunit, distributed-computing, xunit

Is it possible to fetch nUnit/xUnit list of categories using powershell?

Actual problem:
I mark my integration tests that use nunit or xunit with Category/Trait. Each category/trait indicates a component it tests (components are lambdas/funcs, containers). I **somehow fetch this list of components** and store a relationship between the integration test runner (pipeline) and component.

When a container(component) gets up, the event is fired and a lambda needs to know which integration tests to run to ensure integrity.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from the `TestCentric` GUI, which collects all the categories for display.

```
    public IList<string> GetAvailableCategories()
    {
        var categories = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        CollectCategories(Tests, categories);

        var list = new List<string>(categories.Values);
        list.Sort();
        return list;
    }

    private void CollectCategories(TestNode test, Dictionary<string, string> categories)

    {
        foreach (string name in test.GetPropertyList("Category").Split(new[] { ',' }))
            if (IsValidCategoryName(name))
                categories[name] = name;

        if (test.IsSuite)
            foreach (TestNode child in test.Children)
                CollectCategories(child, categories);
    }

    public static bool IsValidCategoryName(string name)
    {
        return name.Length > 0 && name.IndexOfAny(new char[] { ',', '!', '+', '-' }) < 0;
    }
```

I see two ways to go here...

1. Use this code to create a C# program that writes out the list of categories.
2. Emulate this code in Powershell.

In either case, you will need to reference the NUnit engine, either directly or through the engine API.

Obviously, it would be possible for `nunit3-console.exe` to display a list of categories in the same way, but that's not a current feature.